# Multiple lines on top of each other in Julia Plots

Tags: plot, julia

I am using julia plots for plotting different data, however three of the dataseries are almost the same while a fourth is very different. How can I plot the lines and make it clear that there are multiple lines on top of each other?

The simplest thing to do with just two dataseries on top of each other would be to use a dashed line for the second, is something similar same possible for more than two?

Answer (score 2):

There are other `linestyle` you can use like `:dot` and `:dashdot` in addition to `:solid` and `:dash`. You may also want to try different `linealpha`, `linewidth`, or `markershape` to differentiate the lines. The list of all Plots.jl series keyword arguments is [here](https://docs.juliaplots.org/dev/generated/attributes_series/).

```
x = range(0, 1, 101)
plot(x, sqrt, linewidth=5, linealpha=0.5, linestyle=:solid, linecolor=:green)
plot!(x, sqrt, linewidth=5, linealpha=0.5, linestyle=:dash, linecolor=:red)
plot!(x, sqrt, linewidth=5, linealpha=0.5, linestyle=:dot, linecolor=:black)
```

[image]

Comment: Pick better colors than I did: https://juliagraphics.github.io/Colors.jl/dev/namedcolors/